# C++ Const correctness in C wrapper class

Tags: c++, pthreads, const-correctness

Could somebody please give me a little advice regarding const correctness within a C++ wrapper class which encapsulates some legacy C functionality.

Given the following class which partially wraps the pthread mutex API:

```
class Mutex {
private:
  pthread_mutex_t mMutex;

public:
  Mutex();
  void lock();
  void unlock();
  bool tryLock(); };
```

Should the member variable mMutex and the lock(), unlock() and tryLock() methods be declared as const? From a C++ perspective, whilst none of these methods actually change the value of the object, they do appear to change the encapsulated state.

Conceptually, should "const" apply to an object's value, state or both?

Comment: `pthread_mutex_t` could be a structure, and the pthread functions could *directly* modify members of the structure object. Then it just can't be const.

Comment: Side Note: Worth seeing if you can slip in [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex). Could save you a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, but this question pertains to the concept of const correctness rather than the Mutex class itself; what I'm looking for is clarification regarding const value and const state.

Comment: Since `pthread_mutex_t` is an opaque data type, you don't know how or where its internal state is stored. Which means you just can't make it constant. Or mark the functions operating on it constant.

Comment: Surely "changing the [...] state" of the object is not something that anyone would expect a `const`-tagged method call to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell all three functions in `<pthread.h>` take `pthread_mutex_t*` arguments. **NOT** `pthread_mutex_t const*` arguments.

So purely from the technical perspective you already have to make your three member functions non-const as a const member function will have access to `this` as `Mutex const` and its member variable `mMutex` as `pthread_mutex_t const`. Taking its pointer will then require a `const_cast` breaking const correctness.

---

But even if this wasn't the case, it wouldn't seem right to have a function with heavy side effects that can be called from a context that promised not to change the object.

So, in any case, your member functions aren't const.

Comment: Very nicely explained and answer accepted; thank you for clearing-up my confusion regaring this issue.